# MoSync Android : Browse File System

Tags: android, file-browser, mosync

I am creating an app in **MoSync** for **Android and iOS**.

I am using **HTML5/JS/JQuery Mobile**, and I need an example on how to browse a file in a **MoSync App**.

I used simple:

```
<input type="file" />
```

tag, which is rendering normal file browse of HTML.
However, when tapped on it, nothing is there.

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you need, but probably this part of documentation is what you need to read trough ...

http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/file.md.html#File

this functions can get you access to filesystem, but I am afraid that if you need clasis "choose file" dialog, you need to render it yourself.